# realloc(): invalid next size error when reallocating memory for an array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have been going through *Beginning C, Fifth Edition* and I'm currently on chapter 7, which is about pointers. I tried running an example that was given in the chapter but I'm coming across a `realloc(): invalid next size` error when the array gets beyond a capacity of 6 elements. Here's the code which is mostly copied and pasted from the book:

```
// Program 7.14 Using array notation with pointers to sort strings

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_LEN 100                                // Length of input buffer
#define COUNT         5                            // Initial number of strings

int main(void)
{
  char buf[BUF_LEN];                               // Input buffer
  size_t str_count = 0;                            // Current string count
  size_t capacity = COUNT;                         // Current maximum number of strings
  char **pS = calloc(capacity, sizeof(char*));     // Pointers to strings
  char** psTemp = NULL;                            // Temporary pointer to pointer to char
  char* pTemp = NULL;                              // Temporary pointer to char
  size_t str_len = 0;                              // Length of a string
  bool sorted = false;                             // Indicated when strings are sorted
  printf("Enter strings to be sorted, one per line. Press Enter to end:\n");

  // Read in all the strings
  char *ptr = NULL;
  while(true)
  {
    ptr = fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, stdin);
    if(!ptr) // Check for read error
    {
      printf("Error reading string.\n");
      free(pS);
      pS = NULL;
      return 1;
    }

    if(*ptr == '\n') break;             // Empty line check

    if(str_count == capacity)
    {
      capacity += capacity/4;           // Increase capacity by 25%

      if(!(psTemp = realloc(pS, capacity))) return 1;

      pS = psTemp;
    }
    str_len = strnlen(buf, BUF_LEN) + 1;
    if(!(pS[str_count] = malloc(str_len))) return 2;
    strcpy(pS[str_count++], buf);
  }

  // Sort the strings in ascending order
  while(!sorted)
  {
    sorted = true;
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < str_count - 1 ; ++i)
    {
      if(strcmp(pS[i], pS[i + 1]) > 0)
      {
        sorted = false;                 // We were out of order so. . .
        pTemp= pS[i];                   // swap pointers pS[i]. . .
        pS[i] = pS[i + 1];              // and. . .
        pS[i + 1] = pTemp;              // pS[i + 1]
      }
    }
  }

  // Output the sorted strings
  printf("Your input sorted in ascending sequence is:\n\n");
  for(size_t i = 0 ; i < str_count ; ++i)
  {
    printf("%s", pS[i]);
    free(pS[i]);                        // Release memory for the word
    pS[i] = NULL;                       // Reset the pointer
  }
  free(pS);                             // Release the memory for pointers
  pS = NULL;                            // Reset the pointer
  return 0;
}
```

The error happens on this line:

```
if(!(psTemp = realloc(pS, capacity))) return 1;
```

Also, I say the code is "mostly" copied, because the code from the book uses C11 functions like `strnlen_s` and `strcpy_s` which I don't have access to. I'm using `strnlen` and `strcpy` instead. I'm not sure if that is what's causing the issue. Here is the verbatim code from the book however:

```
// Program 7.14 Using array notation with pointers to sort strings
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_LEN 100                                // Length of input buffer
#define COUNT         5                            // Initial number of strings

int main(void)
{
  char buf[BUF_LEN];                               // Input buffer
  size_t str_count = 0;                            // Current string count
  size_t capacity = COUNT;                         // Current maximum number of strings
  char **pS = calloc(capacity, sizeof(char*));     // Pointers to strings
  char** psTemp = NULL;                            // Temporary pointer to pointer to char
  char* pTemp = NULL;                              // Temporary pointer to char
  size_t str_len = 0;                              // Length of a string
  bool sorted = false;                             // Indicated when strings are sorted
  printf("Enter strings to be sorted, one per line. Press Enter to end:\n");

  // Read in all the strings
  char *ptr = NULL;
  while(true)
  {
    ptr = fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, stdin);
    if(!ptr) // Check for read error
    {
      printf("Error reading string.\n");
      free(pS);
      pS = NULL;
      return 1;
    }

    if(*ptr == '\n') break;             // Empty line check

    if(str_count == capacity)
    {
      capacity += capacity/4;           // Increase capacity by 25%

      if(!(psTemp = realloc(pS, capacity))) return 1;

      pS = psTemp;
    }
    str_len = strnlen_s(buf, BUF_LEN) + 1;
    if(!(pS[str_count] = malloc(str_len))) return 2;
    strcpy_s(pS[str_count++], str_len, buf);
  }

  // Sort the strings in ascending order
  while(!sorted)
  {
    sorted = true;
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < str_count - 1 ; ++i)
    {
      if(strcmp(pS[i], pS[i + 1]) > 0)
      {
        sorted = false;                 // We were out of order so. . .
        pTemp= pS[i];                   // swap pointers pS[i]. . .
        pS[i] = pS[i + 1];              // and. . .
        pS[i + 1] = pTemp;              // pS[i + 1]
      }
    }
  }

  // Output the sorted strings
  printf("Your input sorted in ascending sequence is:\n\n");
  for(size_t i = 0 ; i < str_count ; ++i)
  {
    printf("%s", pS[i]);
    free(pS[i]);                        // Release memory for the word
    pS[i] = NULL;                       // Reset the pointer
  }
  free(pS);                             // Release the memory for pointers
  pS = NULL;                            // Reset the pointer
  return 0;
}
```

I have looked up lots of posts on StackOverflow and other places to help me find what's going wrong, but I wasn't able to figure it out. I also used gdb and valgrind to try to diagnose the issue, but I wasn't able to glean much from those tools as well. I am pretty inexperienced with them though, especially valgrind.

I think there's just something small I'm missing. Here's an example of running the program with input taken from the book:

```
Enter strings to be sorted, one per line. Press Enter to end:
Many a mickle makes a muckle.
A fool and your money are soon partners.
Every dog has his day.
Do unto others before they do it to you.
A nod is as good as a wink to a blind horse.
The bigger they are, the harder they hit.
Least said, soonest mended.
realloc(): invalid next size
signal: aborted (core dumped)
```

No matter what the input is, I get that error after 7 lines.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error like that typically happens when you go out of bounds of the allocated memory before calling `realloc`. For example if you allocate to little memory, which you do in the `realloc` calls (the size to reallocate is the amount of *bytes* to allocate, not the amount of "elements").

Comment: I am pretty sure you did not copy the example verbatim. You should do this first. Why do you not have access to C11 functions? What's preventing you from using not-ancient C11-compatible compiler?

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone, @user3121023's solution fixed the issue for me. Should I answer my own question with the solution?

Comment: @SergeyA I am using an online compiler on Replit to run the code, and I guess the compiler there does not have C11 functions. I have also edited the question to include the code taken verbatim from the book.

Comment: @amehdi96 you can use any other online compiler which has C11 support, for example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user3121023's suggestion, I solved it by changing this line:

```
if(!(psTemp = realloc(pS, capacity))) return 1;
```

to this:

```
if(!(psTemp = realloc(pS, capacity * sizeof(*pS)))) return 1;
```

The reason for doing this is because I have to allocate the amount of bytes, not the amount of elements. I'm not sure why the book had it wrong, but I think it's an earlier edition so it's probably fixed in a later edition.